# Finding the integer terms of a binomial expansion

Tags: syntax, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

What functions can I use to find how many integer terms the following expression has?

$$\left (\sqrt[19]{19}+\sqrt[95]{95}\right )^{1995}$$

#### Edit 1

In the development of that binomial, at some point there are terms that are whole numbers, I need to know if in those 1996 terms of development, how many are integers. Which Mathematica functions should I use to find this out?

#### Edit 2

"integer terms" =  an example with other numbers  $\sqrt{8}\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{16}=4$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "integer terms".

Comment: I voted to close this because people are clearly guessing at what you want. I will retract the vote if the question is clarified.

Comment: Indeed.... a VERY useless title.

Comment: @David G. Stork So, what would be the useful title for this case?

Comment: What is "terms of development"?

Answer (score 3):

```
 IntegerLength@IntegerPart[(19^(1/19) + 95^(1/95))^1995]
```

> 690

Comment: After OP clarified, I am pretty sure that this is not what they wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean. I interpret it as if you were looking for the number of integer summands after binomial expansion of the sum.

```
a = 19^(1/19);
b = 95^(1/95);
Count[Table[Binomial[1995, k] a^k b^(1995 - k), {k, 0, 1995}], _Integer]
```

> 22

If my assumption is right, then this will be a somewhat less expensive way to compute this number:

```
k = PadRight[IntegerPartitions[1995, 2]];
{i, j} = Transpose[Join[k, Reverse /@ k]]; 
Count[Mod[i, 19] + Mod[j, 95], 0]
```

> 22

And it is actually

```
Count[Mod[j, 95], 0]
```

> 22

since `19` is a divisor of `95`.

This might also give you a hint on how to solve this exercise on paper.

Comment: That is what I understood too, but others interpret it differently.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like a Math Olympics exercise from 1995...

Comment: Henrik Schumacher  You've hit the nail on the head, that's exactly what I needed, thank you very much, but that 690 that you got before What does it represent?

Comment: `690` is the number of digits of the integer part of the number, so the number of digits in front of the decimal dot of the number's decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ceiling[Log[10, (19^(1/19) + 95^(1/95))^1995]]
(* 690 *)
```

Comment: After OP clarified, I am pretty sure that this is not what they wanted.